# How can I set the font size inside a shape in SlidesApp?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

Until now I haven't found any relation between the shape object and the text font size. And the text that I set is exceeding the shape size limits.

Someone has found a method to deal with that?

Comment: Can you provide your latest script including the issue of ``the text that i set is exceeding the shape limits.``?

Comment: There is no "overflow" setting in native Slides UI, so I doubt it possible to manipulate with API too.

Answer (score 0):

Question pretty old, but I hit same issue, so here is how it's solved, maybe someone also stumble upon it:

```
const shape = slide.insertTextBox(title, 40, 10, 340, 30);

  shape.getText()
       .getTextStyle()
       .setFontSize(21);
```

you can get [Shape](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape) object as other type instance, in our case it's TextRange via Shape.[getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#getText()) method, and that object will have methods you need to style your text